# Is there a way to add multiple values separated with new line in a single cell in google visualization table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-visualization

I have a sql query that fetch data from mysql and group them using GROUP_CONCAT with SEPARATOR '\n'.
Ii works fine when I run it in mysql server. It returns the data with new line if the are grouped. like.

```
---------------------------------
| Year  | Month    | Expenditure|
---------------------------------
|       | Jan      | $2500      |
| 2015  | Feb      | $3200      |
|--------------------------------
|       | April    | $1500      |
| 2016  | May      | $4200      |
|--------------------------------
```

But when I generate the table using Google Visualization it gives me this....

```
---------------------------------
| Year  | Month    | Expenditure|
---------------------------------
|2015   | Jan Feb  | $2500 $3200|
|-------------------------------- 
|2016   | April May| $1500 $4200|
|--------------------------------
```

If there is any chance to solve it please show me...

Comment: You really should not use sql to format your output for display purposes. This should be done by the client that displays your data!

Comment: Okay, but when I directly give the data to google visualization table with '\n' new line separator it dose not understand it. It only gives a space

Comment: In html new line character does not have any significance. Again, do not use sql for formatting your output.

Comment: thank you, so I have to use <br> inside my cell data and set 'allowHtml ' tag to 'true' for the google visualization option

Comment: You are making a huge mistake with that.

Comment: oooooooo.. how?

Comment: Your are using sql to generate data formatting related output as opposed to only retrieve the data and leave formatting to the client displaying the results.